# Запустить .py файл в IDLE в режиме отладки

Tags: python

Как запустить .py файл в IDLE в режиме отладки, для быстрого просмотра ошибок и отладки приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в реестр значения из файла .reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\run]
"MUIVerb"="Отладка в IDLE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\run\command]
@="\"C:\\Python37\\pythonw.exe\" -m idlelib -r \"%L\" %*"
```

Comment: @insolor, для информации....